# How to pass a parameter using QSignalMapper, incompatible sender/receiver arguments

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

Implementation:

```
 void Test::addProcessToList(const QString &command, const QString &id, const BasicInfo &basicInfo) {
        QProcess *console = new QProcess();
        QSignalMapper* signalMapper = new QSignalMapper (this) ;
        connect (console, SIGNAL(readyRead()), signalMapper, SLOT(map())) ;
        connect (console, SIGNAL(finished(int)), signalMapper, SLOT(processFinished(int))) ;
        signalMapper->setMapping (console, id) ;
        connect (signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(pidOut(QString))) ;
        console->start(command);
    }

    void Test::registerProcess(QString id) {
        QProcess *console = qobject_cast<QProcess*>(QObject::sender());
        QByteArray processOutput = console->readAll();
        int mainPID = parsePID(processOutput);

        BasicInfo basicInfo;
        qDebug() << "Registering id: " + id + " mainPID: " + mainPID;
        if(mainPID != 0) {
            Main::getInstance()->addProcessToList(mainPID, packageId, basicInfo);
        } else {
            qWarning() << "pidOut Error fetching mainPID";
        }
    }


    void Test::processFinished(int exitCode) {
        QProcess *console = qobject_cast<QProcess*>(QObject::sender());
        QByteArray processOutput = console->readAll() + QString("Finished with code %1").arg(exitCode).toLatin1();
        qDebug() << " processFinished: " + processOutput;
    }
```

prototypes:

```
private
    void addProcessToList(const QString &command, const QString &id, const BasicInfo &basicInfo);

private slots:
    void registerProcess(QString);
    void processFinished(int);
```

I get this errors when I call connect, which tells me I'm doing it wrong:

"QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments
                                               QSignalMapper::mapped(int) --> Test::registerProcess(QString)"

I'm not understanding where I'm suppose to specify my parameter (QString id) so that registerProcess will receive it when it's called? I'm assuming I'm doing this part wrong, cut from above:

```
signalMapper->setMapping (console, id) ;
        connect (signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(pidOut(QString))) ;
```

Comment: Your signal/sender is sending an 'int' and your slot/receiver expects a `QString`. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Also suspect: `connect (console, SIGNAL(finished(int)), signalMapper, SLOT(processFinished(int))) ;` - I'm pretty sure that `QSignalMapper` doesn't have a `processFinished` slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QSignalMapper` can emit either `mapped(const QString & text)` or `mapped(int i)` signals. The type is defined by `setMapping(QObject * sender, int id)` or `setMapping(QObject * sender, const QString & text)`.

That led to confusion probably by autocompletion in

```
connect (signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(pidOut(QString)));
```

The types of signal and slot must be the same for connection.

You set string mapping (`QString &id`), so the signal in the connection should be `QString`:

```
connect (signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), this, SLOT(pidOut(QString)));
```

---

Update

After deeper review of the code flow I suspect that you wanted to connect mapper to `registerProcess()` slot instead of `pidOut()`. In that slot you can have as an argument `QString id` that was passed to `signalMapper` in `setMapping()` call. That is the purpose of using `QSignalMapper`.

However, beside that `id` it is not possible to extract `console` pointer, since in that case `sender()` is `signalMapper` object. If it is the case, `QSignalMapper` cannot help you here. You should use direct connection of `console` and `this` on `readReady` (of course with slot of `this` with `void` argument as `readReady()`). To get the string `id` in that slot it is possible to use simple `QMap<QProces*, QString> map` stored as a `Test` class member.

```
// addProcessToList(...):
map[console] = id;

//registerProcess():
QString id = map[console];

//processFinished(...):
map.remove(console);
```

---

By the way, it is not needed to created a new instance of `QSignalMapper` for each map item.

Comment: Thank-you for this, I ended up following your idea to use a class member and have the call backs retrieve the params from this lookup